# Increase stack size in runtime in Swi-prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, stack-size

I used `set_prolog_flag(stack_limit, 5000000000).` in my code.

But then i got the following error:

`ERROR:    No permission to modify static procedure "set_prolog_flag/2"`

It seem that i don't have persmission to modify stack_size.Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Maybe this might help: https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/StackSizes.html

Comment: Seems you added it as a fact. You need to issue this as a goal, say, on the top level or as a directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emolai, it seems that you consulted info out of date.
You need to set the stack limits this way:

:- set_prolog_stack(stack, limit(5000000000)).

See the colon+minus? This signify that the goal set_prolog_stack/2 is to be executed and not defining a new clause set_prolog_stack/2. This explains the error you got.

You are now good to go. Is your question solved ?

Comment: Thank you,i actually solved the issue by reading the comment by @false. Thank you for your time as well :)